# Reaction Commerce setup on Windows 10 Home

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, reaction-commerce

Now its been 2 weeks and i am trying to setup the environment for reaction commerce, but i am failing everytime, i don't want to giveup on it.

I have tried on windows and linux both, following are my points:

**Windows**  ---  I have windows 10 home, i tried to install dockers and unfortunately, it is not supporting home version then i tried with virtual box, it also starting giving error.

**Ubuntu 16** --- I installed the ubuntu app for windows and then i tried to set up on that, and then failed cause my system was not supporting docker.

Can anyone please help me in the setup of the environment.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if You fixed the issue as it has been some time. But You have to install WSL2 for docker to run on windows 10 home.

Comment: it does, if You install WSL2, I have windows 10 home, and it works: https://hub.docker.com/editions/community/docker-ce-desktop-windows/